# comparing user given time for log file time

Tags: grep, awk, time

Apologies straight away for bad-styled-question-and-heading.....learning unix  and its command these days, m trying to figure out a solution for below scenario :

Lets say i have a log file which looks like :

```
 01-02-1988     12:00:00    I start 
 01-02-1988     12:00:01    I start
 01-02-1988     12:00:02    I start 
 01-02-1988     12:00:03    I start
 01-02-1988     12:00:04    I start 
 01-02-1988     12:00:05    I start
 01-02-1988     12:00:06    I start 
 01-02-1988     12:00:07    I start
 01-02-1988     12:00:08    I start 
 01-02-1988     12:00:09    I start
 01-02-1988     01:00:10    I start
```

and i take a time bracket from user for which he wants to see the status.To filter out all the process, i can do :

```
egrep $usr_time log.txt
```

But is there any way i can do the same for a particular time period, like `awk`, can match the value for me for `$2` here...but how to compare it for seconds(ss in hh:mm:ss)???

Like for example : assume i  want records from `12:00:01 - 12:00:06`, so basically what i would need is to extract 3rd value from `:` delimiter and compare it....how can this be achieved....please help!!!!

Comment: The last line should be the first. The sorting is wrong.

Comment: @HaukeLaging : its just a template log file...not the real one, i showed just to get visitors familiar with the format of log file...plus its in 12hrs format, not 24hr!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can be sure that the entries are in time order then you can use both times (if both exist in the file!) as start and stop addresses:

```
start cmd:> sed -n -e /12:00:03/,/12:00:09/p file
01-02-1988     12:00:03    I start
01-02-1988     12:00:04    I start 
01-02-1988     12:00:05    I start
01-02-1988     12:00:06    I start 
01-02-1988     12:00:07    I start
01-02-1988     12:00:08    I start 
01-02-1988     12:00:09    I start
```

If it is possible that the start and stop time do not appear in the file then you have to compare (it may be necessary to include the date in this calculation)

```
awk -v starttime="12:00:03" -v stoptime="12:00:09" \
  'BEGIN {FS=":"; $0=starttime; startts=$1*3600+$2*60+$3; '\
  '$0=stoptime; stopts=$1*3600+$2*60+$3; FS=" ";}; ' \
  '{line=$0; FS=":"; $0=$2; secs=$1*3600+$2*60+$3; if (secs>stopts) exit; '\
  'if (secs>=startts) print line; FS=" ";}' file
```

The strings can even be compared directly:

```
awk -v starttime="12:00:03" -v stoptime="12:00:09" \
  '{line=$0; if ($2>stoptime) exit; '\
  'if ($2>=starttime) print line; FS=" ";}' file
```

Comment: this is much cleaner as i dont need to cmpare in seconds but m generating the log from `sql`, so `start` and `end time` are not surely present in the log, any workarounds....when time bounds are missing from log file???

Comment: @NoobEditor That makes the solution "a bit" more complicated...

Comment: haha... your 'bit' is rocket-science for me fella!!! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor And that doesn't even cover AM/PM yet. You may accept the answer now.

Comment: is there anything like comparing time which can do something like `start_time > user_start_time && end_time <= user_end_time`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the contents are in a file `x.txt`, you can achieve this as follows:

```
awk ' $2~/12:00:0[1-6]/ { print }' x.txt
```

The expression `$2~/12:00:0[1-6]/` will evaluate the second column against provided regex and the print statement will print all matching rows. If you want to print just the second column of each row, you can do `print $2` and so on.

To include shell variables in `awk`, use `-v`, eg:

```
ss=1 es=6 awk -v reg=12:00:0[$ss-$es] ' $2 ~ reg { print }' x.txt
```

I suggest to check out this beautifully written `awk` user documentation : http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html

Comment: assuming i take start and end second from user in `ss` and `es` variables,`awk '$2~/12:00:[$ss-$es]/ {print;}` throws and error of  `awk: fatal: Invalid range end: /12:00:[$ss-$es]/`

Comment: `prompt > $ ss=1 es=6 awk -v reg=12:00:0[$ss-$es] ' $2 ~ reg { print }' x.txt` From awk user manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Using-Shell-Variables.html